# ios- is "swapping" UIViews possible?

Tags: ios, view

Here's my code:

```
if([pantallas objectForKey:par]){
    UIView *vista= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.Botones.frame];
    vista.backgroundColor= [UIColor brownColor];

    CGSize la=  CGSizeMake(50,60);
    int cuantos= [part2 count];
    NSArray *arr= [COLGenerales tileN:cuantos RectsOfSize:la  intoSpaceOf:vista.frame withMaxPerRow:5 spaceVertical:10 spaceHorizontal:10];
    for(int j=0; j<cuantos; j++){
        UIButton *bot= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:[[arr objectAtIndex:j] CGRectValue]];
        bot.tag=j;
        bot.titleLabel.text=par;
        bot.titleLabel.hidden=true;
        bot.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[part2 allKeys] objectAtIndex:j]];
        [bot addTarget:self action:@selector(registrar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [vista addSubview:bot];

    }

    [pantallas setObject:vista forKey:par];

   self.Botones= vista; 
    }else{
    self.Botones= [pantallas objectForKey:par];
}
```

Botones is a simple view embedded into the view this class controls (first initiated by the Nib file), the class method of COLGenerales returns an array of CGRects coded as NSValues, and  registrar: is a local method.

Everything gets properly set (I've thoroughly checked this with the debugger). The view gets successfully created, set, and added to the dictionary.

However, I absolutely never get the actual screen to change. I even included the background color change just to check if it isn't some kind of problem with the buttons. Nothing. Any suggested solution to this?

Comment: Where does this code live, and how is it called? And when is this view added to an onscreen view?

Comment: Within a function of the controller of a detail view, and this gets called by a master view. Botones itself is part of the detail scene (with its IBOutlet property set as `strong`), and I assume changing its value should reflect on the onscreen content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property that is an IBOutlet does not have an intrinsic connection to the view hierarchy—it only makes it possible to populate that property from a xib.  When you set self.Botones, you'll need to do something like the following:

```
[self.Botones removeFromSuperview];
self.Botones = newValue;
[self.BotonesSuperview addSubview:self.Botones];
```

If you update `self.Botones` in many places, and you always want the change reflected on-screen, you could add this into a setter implementation:

```
-(void)setBotones:(UIView*)newValue {
    if (newValue != _Botones) {
        [_Botones removeFromSuperview];
        _Botones = newValue;
        [self.BotonesSuperview addSubview:_Botones];
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, but now buttons are not displaying. Must they, as objects, be at a given scope before being added? The subview counter itself of _Botones is increasing.

Comment: Don't user `button.imageView.image`, use `[button setImage:forState:]`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a UINavigation controller that houses these two views.

You can reference this link [Swapping between UIViews in one UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003318/swapping-between-uiviews-in-one-uiviewcontroller)

Basically, you create one view, removeSubview for the first and then add the second one with addSubview!

[view1 removeFromSuperview];

[self.view addSubview: view2];

Other reference sources:
[An easy, clean way to switch/swap views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982287/an-easy-clean-way-to-switch-swap-views)

[How to animate View swap on simple View iPhone App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983598/how-to-animate-view-swap-on-simple-view-iphone-app)

Hopefully this helps!